Performance of Lapack's DORMQR vs. DORM2R
I was benchmarking the blocked (DORMQR) and the non-blocked (DORM2R) Lapack function which applies Q from a QR factorization to another matrix C, so C = Q * C.
My expectation would be that the blocked version is faster than the unblocked version. Even if the flop count might be higher, the advantage comes by better cache utilization, higher level BLAS routines and so on. But the number I see are quite the opposite. Any idea on that?
I was using square matrices with size BlockSize times BlockSize. Here are my numbers for 500 repetitions:



BlockSize
Method
Time
Factor




32
xORM2R
0.000169992
1.19355


32
xORMQR
0.000202894



64
xORM2R
0.000250101
249.983


64
xORMQR
0.062521



128
xORM2R
0.000559092
151.6319


128
xORMQR
0.0847762



256
xORM2R
0.00103307
151.2085


256
xORMQR
0.156209



512
xORM2R
0.00210094
309.8199


512
xORMQR
0.650913



1024
xORM2R
0.00397611
1258.325


1024
xORMQR
5.00324



2048
xORM2R
0.00847983
2600.63


2048
xORMQR
22.0529



4096
xORM2R
0.0168719
10778.93


4096
xORMQR
181.861




I was first running this with my Lapack installation and afterwards with Intel MKL's version of Lapack and did get the same numbers. Am I missing something?
